# Redirecting subdomains in Godaddy with IIS7

Tags: iis-7, redirect

Is it possible redirect all subdomains to a specific URL?

**I'm using Godaddy Hosting (Windows Plan - IIS7)**

Generic example 1:

```
*.mysite.com

REDIRECT TO

mysite.com/pages/*
```

Example 2:

```
anysubdomain.mysite.com

REDIRECT TO

mysite.com/pages/anysubdomain
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725815(WS.10).aspx)

> The procedures for configuring HTTP
>   redirection can be performed at the
>   following levels in IIS:
>
> 1. Web Server
> 2. Site
> 3. Application
> 4. Physical and virtual directories
> 5. File (URL)

By itself I don't think IIS 7 supports subdomain redirection.

You need something like [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite) which will allow you to make a catch all or regex rule for subdomain redirection, but I am not sure if GoDaddy allows you to install modules, or if they will install that module for you.

Comment: So in short, contact customer support.

Comment: Yes, but at least you know it is possible with the right tool. Now you just have to convince them to install it for you.